# MeteorJS on Windows 7: error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: ssl, meteor, certificate, chain

I try to test MeteorJS on Windows. I downloaded the last version of Meteor (1.5.2).

At my workplace, when I tryed to create a new project with "meteor create simple-todos", as Admin or not, I had an error:

> C:\DEV\METEORJS>meteor create simple-todos
>
> => Errors while creating your project
>
> While downloading blaze@2.3.2...: error: self signed certificate in
>   certificate chain
>
> While downloading blaze-html-templates@1.1.2...: error: self signed
>   certificate in certificate chain
>
> While downloading blaze-tools@1.0.10...: error: self signed
>   certificate in certificate chain
>   ...

At home, I retry this test as Admin, and it run well :

> C:\DEV\METEORJS>meteor create simple-todos
>
> Created a new Meteor app in
>   'simple-todos'.
>
> To run your new app:   cd simple-todos   meteor
>
> ...

What could explain this error?
Could this affect the operation or reliability of an application built with Meteor?

Comment: Are you behind some firewall that inspects SSL?

Comment: Hi Styx, it's possible for my office.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy

Comment: Also, at this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7499

Comment: Thanks for your help... I saw the last link, but I don't read it to the end, because it's an ubuntu issue. I'll test it tomorrow. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved with my "network manager" !

There isn't any proxy on the office's firewall, but there was a module that decrypted the SSL stream. After deactivating it, I was able to create my Meteor project.

Thank you @Styx for giving me the right track (with your first answer).